# Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently using Spring OAuth2Client version `5.2.4.RELEASE` in my project.

I have implemented Spring Security by referring to the Official Spring Docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-authorized-manager-provider).

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean("AuthProvider")
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations, ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                clientRegistrations,
                authorizedClients);
        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("AuthProvider");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .filter(this.logRequest())
                .build();
    }

    
    private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
            log.info("Request: [{}] {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
            log.debug("Payload: {}", clientRequest.body());
            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }
```

**application.yaml**

```
   security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          AuthProvider:
            token-uri: ${tokenpath<read from environment variable>}
        registration:
          AuthProvider:
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials
            client-id: ${<read from environment variable>}
            client-secret: ${<read from environment variable>}
```

Getting the following error on the application startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method webClient in com.sample.config.WebClientConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

Kindly point me out if I have missed any configuration. Also, I didn't get much help from other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: plz add POM  file

Comment: Do you have clientRegistrations bean configured? If not look for it in the same docs and add a bean.

Comment: @BryanMusial which spring-boot version are you using ?

Comment: @BryanMusial The problem is with application.yml.

Comment: @BryanMusial Added the solution. Plz refer.

Comment: is this a reactive or servlet appllication?

Comment: Dear @AnishB. could you check my answer, i has the same problem but your solution didn't work for me

Comment: @AnishB. i added my own answer in the below of current question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446695/consider-defining-a-bean-of-type-org-springframework-security-oauth2-client-reg#answer-62895013

Comment: @RasoolGhafari Have you solved or problem still exists ?

Comment: Problem solved, but i want to know why your solution didn't worked for me?

Comment: @RasoolGhafari I already added that dependency in pom.xml that you provided. You didn't see that I guess.

Comment: @AnishB. which dependency? i do all of configurations that you suggested, also the dependencies, but didn't worked, so, i used the dependencies that you can see in my answer and my own configurations

Answer (score 30):

Your spring-boot configuration is perfect.

---

**Root cause of the issue:** The problem is in **application.yaml.** Either the configuration is wrong or not picked from the environment.

*So, the problem is not the **OAuth2 version** but the configuration in **application.yaml.***

**Note :** `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` bean is created only
when you configure the client with the OAuth2 application owner details.

---

I created a new project from [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) and used your configuration in that.

And after running the project with your configuration, I was facing the same issue.

Error log :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method webClient in com.example.sampleoauth2.WebClientConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'clientRegistrationRepository' in 'ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfigurations.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration' not loaded because OAuth2 Clients Configured Condition registered clients is not available


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' in your configuration.
```

---

Then, I saw that I didn't configure properties in **application.yml** file.

*I read [Spring Boot and OAuth2.0 Docs](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) about how to get client-id and client-secret from github (Example) as you register your spring-boot app as OAuth app in that.*

As soon as, I configured my application started to work.

---

I'm using **spring-boot 2.3.1.RELEASE** and **OAuth2Client version 5.3.3**.

My **pom.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>sampleOauth2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sampleOauth2</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My client github registration properties for **application.yml**:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: 22a7100de41c7308d346
            client-secret: 05910ab890be29579e9c183443d92e756c450aaf
```

Your updated **WebClientConfig** @Configuration class :

```
package com.example.sampleoauth2;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
        oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).filter(this.logRequest()).build();
    }

    private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
            log.info("Request: [{}] {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
            log.debug("Payload: {}", clientRequest.body());
            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }
}
```

Success Log :

```
   .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

2020-06-26 20:36:08.380  INFO 15956 --- [           main] c.e.s.SampleOauth2Application            : Starting SampleOauth2Application on Anishs-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 15956 (/Users/anish/Downloads/sampleOauth2/target/classes started by anish in /Users/anish/Downloads/sampleOauth2)
2020-06-26 20:36:08.381  INFO 15956 --- [           main] c.e.s.SampleOauth2Application            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-06-26 20:36:08.935  INFO 15956 --- [           main] ctiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 7c63302f-f913-4aa1-852d-cb8445719acb

2020-06-26 20:36:09.132  INFO 15956 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
2020-06-26 20:36:09.138  INFO 15956 --- [           main] c.e.s.SampleOauth2Application            : Started SampleOauth2Application in 0.978 seconds (JVM running for 1.313)
```

Comment: @BryanMusial Is this helpful ?

Comment: Yes, though in my own case the root cause was not the app config, but some commingling of Servlet and Reactive components.  Once correcting those references my solution began to work.  That said, thank you for throwing together an example; Bounty awarded!

Comment: Any chance you could be more specific Bryan?  I am facing a similar issue and I am pretty bare bones ... Which servlet and which reactive components where in the same project?

Answer (score 18):

I am using spring boot 2.3.1.RELEASE
I had the same problem, my pom.xml contained both these dependencies in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I removed the following dependency and that did the trick for me :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Not saying this will resolve your hassle but this might also be a dependency conflict issue for you.

This other post put me on track : [Reactive OAuth2 with Spring Security 5.3.2 ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository bean could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61800834/reactive-oauth2-with-spring-security-5-3-2-reactiveclientregistrationrepository)

Answer (score 10):

`ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` is come with `Reactive stack (netty)`, not with `Servlet stack (tomcat)`

In case your `pom.xml` include `spring-boot-starter-web`, Spring understand that you use `Servlet stack`, it will load `ClientRegistrationRepository` instead of `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository`

To create bean of `WebClient`, two solution you can use:

#### Solution 1:

Remove `spring-boot-starter-web` from `pom.xml` so Spring understand you are in  `Reactive stack`

```
@Bean
WebClient webClient(
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
    ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService
) {
    var oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
            new AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService
            )
        );

    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("AuthProvider");
    return WebClient.builder()
        .filter(oauth)
        .build();
}
```

#### Solution 2:

Keep `spring-boot-starter-web` in `pom.xml`

```
@Bean // with spring-boot-starter-web
WebClient webClient(
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService
) {
    var oauth = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
        new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService
        )
    );
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("AuthProvider");
    return WebClient.builder()
      .apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration())
      .build();
}
```

Comment: Solution number #3 to conflicting dependencies (when you can't find culprit for example) is to set application type to `reactive` like explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71234523/5562284

`spring.main.web-application-type=reactive`

Answer (score 6):

I used the configurations that @AnishB. suggested as answer but still got the error:

```
Parameter 0 of method webClient in com.example.sampleoauth2.WebClientConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.
```

So, i had to use these dependencies with **spring 2.3.1.RELEASE**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And this the `WebClientConfig` class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebClientConfig.class);

    @Bean("cr")
    ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository getRegistration(
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret}") String clientSecret
    ) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId("keycloak")
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean(name = "keycloak")
    WebClient webClient(@Qualifier("cr") ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("keycloak");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .filter(logRequest())
                .build();
    }

    private ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
        return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
            log.info("Request: [{}] {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url());
            log.debug("Payload: {}", clientRequest.body());

            return Mono.just(clientRequest);
        });
    }
}
```

and everything works fine, but it is question for me that why the solution of @AnishB. didn't worked for me?!

Comment: This `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux` is already prsent in my pom.xml. Please check it properly.

Comment: That's why I added my pom.xml

Comment: It depends I lot of factors are there for getting this error.

Comment: Yes, i know that you used `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, i used as same as you used in the pom.xml, but didn't worked for me and i had to use my own configurations that i found it at https://manhtai.github.io/posts/spring-webclient-oauth2-client-credentials/

Comment: It is very exciting for me that your configurations didn't worked for me and interesting to know the reason.

Comment: just this kind of configuration helped me . thanks

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71807202/836376

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'm using `WebClient` in **spring-batch** application `(WebApplicationType.NONE)`. So no servlet context is found, hence I had to configure `ClientRegistrationRepository`, `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`, `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` by myself.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationsRepository(
            @Value("${keycloak.registration-id}") String registrationId,
            @Value("${keycloak.token-uri}") String tokenUri,
            @Value("${keycloak.client-id}") String clientId,
            @Value("${keycloak.client-secret}") String clientSecret) {
        ClientRegistration registration = ClientRegistration
                .withRegistrationId(registrationId)
                .tokenUri(tokenUri)
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .authorizationGrantType(CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .build();
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(registration);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientService oAuth2AuthorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationsRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationsRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {

        OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .clientCredentials()
                        .build();

        AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientService);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

        return authorizedClientManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager,
                               @Value("${keycloak.registration-id}") String registrationId) {

        ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction auth2Function =
                new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        auth2Function.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(registrationId);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .apply(auth2Function.oauth2Configuration())
                .build();

    }
}
```

```yaml
keycloak:
  registration-id: my-registration
  client-id: my-parameters
  client-secret: g92olxcwBIWYNuSDaEyZrBsYHQPCv04R
  token-uri: http://localhost:8090/auth/realms/my-realm/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

and added theses dependenciens:

```
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client"
```

Answer (score 0):

it is the dependency conflict issue. Try removing the web dependency

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this code to   your application.yml oe application.properties

server:
spring:
security:
oauth2:
resourceserver:
jwt:
jwk-set-uri: keycloakHost:port/realms/YourRealmenter code here/protocol/openid-connect/certs

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, my version of spring security was 6.15 I had both of these annotations @EnableWebFluxSecurity @Configuration of my class definition I found out that my issue was in the application.yml configuration entry
spring:security:oauth2:resourceServer:jwt:kwk-set-uri:

In my case it was not aligned to be under spring: so it appeared as if I had not defined it in the .yml file

Start by making sure you have it defined and check that it is aligned correctly within the .yml file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case just forgot to add issuer-uri for resouce server:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri: http://${app.auth-server}:9999
```